# VS Code - With word wrap on, make "Add Cursor Above/Below" select next "real" line

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, is there a setting which when `Word Wrap` is `on` lets `Add Cursor Above/Below` select the *real* next line instead of the wrapped one?

So instead of this behavior...

[image: VSCode - Add Cursor Above/Below behavior with word wrap]

...select the next line like with holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>:

[image: VSCode - Add Cursor holding Alt key]

Comment: Seems related to https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/66510